# How to Set the Newer Version of dot (a tool of graphviz)?

Tags: centos, software-installation, graphviz

I wanted to use doxygen 1.8.5 on CentOS 7 which uses dot to produce graphs of source codes. dot is a tool of graphviz package. I downloaded [graphviz 2.42](https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/portable_source/) and installed it by going through the following steps: (1) `./configure` (2) `make`, and (3) `make install`.
I, then, decided to use the latest version of graphviz (version 2.44) to prevent some bugs and issues of the older version 2.42.

To do this, I tried to uninstall the graphviz 2.42 using the command `yum autoremove graphviz`. Then, I used this [installation guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/graphviz.html) to install graphviz 2.44. Graphviz 2.44 is successfully installed but the version of dot is still 2.42. I checked it with `dot -V`.

Why the version of the dot is still 2.42 while graphviz 2.44 is installed? How can I change the version of dot to the most recently installed one?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `sudo make uninstall` in the source directory?

Comment: That Worked! Thanks

Comment: A bit off topic but: You want to use doxygen 1.8.5 from August 2013, the current version is 1.8.20 (I'm not sure that doxygen 1.8.5 will work together with dot 2.44).

Comment: @albert I installed it because it was the version in centos.pkgs.org. But, I have an issue with doxygen 1.8.5. It is about dot. I get the error: png not recognized. I searched about it and 'dot -c' is suggested to solve this issue. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you solve the problem as the answer (about the uninstall) is accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the compiled program, in the source directory run:

```
sudo make uninstall
```